# @Transactional in nested transaction scenario - switch between RW and RO connection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have a scenario where I wanted to execute child1 in a readOnly transaction and child2 in a read-write transaction, and both inside an over arching transaction.
If something goes wrong in child1 or child2, I just wanted to rollback the over arching transaction.

```
@Transactional
parentMethod(){
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .setCurrentTransactionName("TestTransaction");
  log.info("Current Transaction Name - parentMethod ::: " + 
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .getCurrentTransactionName());
  log.info("Is the transaction readonly - parentMethod ::: " + 
  TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly());
  child1();
  child2();
}

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
child1(){
  log.info("Current Transaction Name - child1 ::: " + 
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .getCurrentTransactionName());
  log.info("Is the transaction readonly - child1 ::: " + 
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .isCurrentTransactionReadOnly());
}

@Transactional
child2(){
  log.info("Current Transaction Name - child2 ::: " + 
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .getCurrentTransactionName());
  log.info("Is the transaction readonly - child2 ::: " + 
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .isCurrentTransactionReadOnly());
}
```

***Output log shows:***

```
Current Transaction Name - parentMethod ::: TestTransaction
Is the transaction readonly - parentMethod ::: false
Current Transaction Name - child1 ::: null
Is the transaction readonly - child1 ::: false
Current Transaction Name - child2 ::: null
Is the transaction readonly - child2 ::: false
```

Whereas, if I set *TransactionSynchronizationManager.setCurrentTransactionReadOnly(true)* deliberately inside child1 method, output changes slight as I expected.

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
child1(){
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .setCurrentTransactionReadOnly(true);
  log.info("Current Transaction Name - child1 ::: " + 
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .getCurrentTransactionName());
  log.info("Is the transaction readonly - child1 ::: " + 
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .isCurrentTransactionReadOnly());
}
```

***Output log shows:***

```
Current Transaction Name - parentMethod ::: TestTransaction
Is the transaction readonly - parentMethod ::: false
Current Transaction Name - child1 ::: null
Is the transaction readonly - child1 ::: true
Current Transaction Name - child2 ::: null
Is the transaction readonly - child2 ::: false
```

I just wanted to know whether something is wrong in whatever I was doing. Or is there a better way to do it. However, the Current Transaction Name inside child1 and child2 is still null, which I would expect to be as "TestTransaction", which was set in parentMethod.

Also, just wondering which one takes precedence, readOnly or the propagation level when there are nested transactions with these values set differently.

Comment: There is only a single transaction and you cannot change that while it is ongoing. Also it is an internal method call so the `@Transactional` is pretty much useless on those methods.

Comment: Hi @Denim, I don't  necessarily agree with you. As per your comment, if we can't change an ongoing transaction, then setting `TransactionSynchronizationManager.setCurrentTransactionReadOnly(true)` deliberately inside `child1` method shouldn't have worked. Setting `TransactionSynchronizationManager.setCurrentTransactionReadOnly(true)` converted an ongoing read-write transaction to be readonly, which is clearly seen from the output log `Is the transaction readonly - child1 ::: true`

Comment: You are only setting a thread-local property, you aren't actually changing the underlying active transaction. So yes it appears so but the actually result is nothing has changed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Denim. However, I still don't clearly understand your point here... Meanwhile, I was just trying to play around with this did a small change which looks to me like doing trans mgt programatically. All I did was - removed `@Transactional` from `child1()`, so that it is still under an over arching transaction created from `parentmethod()`, and explicitly set and unset `setCurrentTransactionReadOnly` inside `child1()` like `TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .setCurrentTransactionReadOnly(true);`

Comment: This is what pretty much what I was trying and looks to be working I expected....   `child1(){
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .setCurrentTransactionReadOnly(true);
  log.info("Current Transaction Name - child1 ::: " + 
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .getCurrentTransactionName());
  log.info("Is the transaction readonly - child1 ::: " + 
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .isCurrentTransactionReadOnly());
    TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .setCurrentTransactionReadOnly(false);
}`

Comment: The `@Transactional` on the `child1` and `child2` methods are pretty much useless. (As I stated in my first comment). As I also stated you are only setting a thread local property you aren't actually changing the ongoing active transaction (the one at the database level). So yes your logging might say it switched to read only, if you check the actual ongoing transaction on the database level nothing has changed. As I stated it is only a thread local property you aren't influencing anything besides that property.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Transactional
parentMethod(){
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .setCurrentTransactionName("TestTransaction");
  log.info("Current Transaction Name - parentMethod ::: " + 
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .getCurrentTransactionName());
  log.info("Is the transaction readonly - parentMethod ::: " + 
  TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly());
  child1();
  child2();
}

child1(){
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .setCurrentTransactionReadOnly(true);
  log.info("Current Transaction Name - child1 ::: " + 
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .getCurrentTransactionName());
  log.info("Is the transaction readonly - child1 ::: " + 
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .isCurrentTransactionReadOnly());
    TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .setCurrentTransactionReadOnly(false);
}

child2(){
  log.info("Current Transaction Name - child2 ::: " + 
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .getCurrentTransactionName());
  log.info("Is the transaction readonly - child2 ::: " + 
  TransactionSynchronizationManager
  .isCurrentTransactionReadOnly());
}
```

This seems to work for me. I'm kind of mixing both programmatic and declarative way of handling transactions here. I just have one over arching `@Transactional` annotation on `parentMethod`and explicitly set and unset `readonly` as and when required. Can someone please give your comment or opinion on this?